# Проблема с списками

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал скрипт для поиска папки по названию, возвращает адрес в системе. Все вроде бы работает, кроме списков. Первый раз подкаталоги добавляются, и больше не добавляются

```
def search(title, unverified = [os.getcwd()], suitable = []):
    if not unverified: #рекурсия заканчивается, если не осталось адресов для поиска
        return suitable #возвращаем список адресов папок, которые совпали с название
    parent = unverified.pop() #извлекам адрес из очереди, для обработки(родитель)
    try:
        children = list(filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(parent))) #берем подкаталоги(дети) из родителя)))), если доступ закрыт вернется исключение
        for child in children: #берем ребенка из кучи
            address = os.path.normpath(parent + os.sep + child) #составляем его адрес
            unverified.append(address)#отправляем адрес ребенка в очередь(потом проверим, если у него дети)
            if child == title: #если имя ребенка совпало с искомым, то добавляем его адрес в искомые
                suitable.append(address)
    except PermissionError: #если отказ в доступе, то пропускаем папку
        pass
    return search(title, unverified, suitable)
```

Как я понял не добавляются элементы в список. Как решить не пойму и в инете не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

В Python значения по умолчанию для параметров функции рассчитываются только один раз — в момент объявления функции.

Поэтому использовать в качестве значения по умолчнию массив не очень хорошая идея — по сути все вызовы функций используют один и тот же массив `unverified`, изменяя его по ссылке (аналогично с `suitable`)

Правильнее делать как-то так:

```
def search(unverified = None, suitable = None):
    if unverified is None:
        unverified = [os.getcwd()]

    if suitable is None:
        suitable = []

    # ...
```

Comment: Проблема в другом... Пробовал все сделать через while, но ситуация та же, данные в массив не добавляются, как будто их нет

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в `children = list(filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(parent)))`.
Чтобы решить проблему пришлось сделать свой фильтр и сделать вместо рекурсии - цикл.

```
children = os.listdir(parent) # дети извлекаются без фильтра
```

фильтр вместо детей поставил на родителя

```
if not os.path.isdir(parent):
    continue
```